# Hive: filter a table using another table

Tags: sql, filter, hive

I am very new to hive and sql and I have a question about how I would go about the following:

I have table A:

```
Name    id

Amy     1
Bob     4
Josh    9
Sam     6
```

And I want to filter it using values from another table (table B):

```
Value  id

.2     4
.7     6
```

To get a new table that looks like table A but only contains rows with values in the id column that also appeared in the id column of table B:

```
Name    id

Bob     4
Sam     6
```

So I'm assuming I would write something that started like...

```
CREATE TABLE Table C AS
SELECT * FROM Table A
WHERE id....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for the result I wanted was:

```
CREATE TABLE tableC AS
SELECT tableA.*
FROM tableA LEFT SEMI JOIN tableB on (tableA.id = tableB.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

just join it..

```
hive> CREATE TABLE TableC AS           
    > SELECT A.* FROM TableA as A,
    > TableB as B                       
    > WHERE A.id = B.id;

hive> SELECT * FROM TableC;
OK
Bob 4
Sam 6
```

or try this,

```
hive> CREATE TABLE TableD AS           
    > SELECT A.* FROM TableA as A join
    > TableB as B                       
    > on A.id = B.id;

hive> SELECT * FROM TableD;
OK
Bob 4
Sam 6
```

Comment: I tried running the following:

`CREATE TABLE tableC AS`           
     `SELECT A.* FROM tableA as A,`
     `tableB as B`                     
     `WHERE A.id = B.2;`

and got `error while compiling statement: failed: parseexception line 2:34 missing eof at ',' near 'a'`

I feel like I encounter this sort of error a lot.  Does it have to do with the version of Hive I'm running?  Or perhaps this is valid in SQL but not Hive?

Comment: see your query , you have written WHERE A.id = B.2, write WHERE A.id = B.id

Comment: that is not the problem, I am editing out variable names and simply made a typo.

Comment: The second solution runs without error but returns a table with more rows than the one I started with

Comment: Write Inner join instead of join

Comment: 'Inner join' does not exist in hive, the equivalent is 'join'

Answer (score 0):

Two tables were created with the below columns

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1 
( NAMES VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
ID_1 NUMBER (2) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE TABLE_2 
( VALUES_1 VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
ID_1 NUMBER (2) NOT NULL)
```

and inserted values in these tables

Final table should be created as

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_3 AS (
SELECT T1.NAMES,T2.ID_1 FROM TABLE_1 T1,TABLE_2 T2
WHERE T1.ID_1(+)= T2.ID_1)
```

Comment: I tried: 

    CREATE TABLE newtable AS
    SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1,  table2 t2
    WHERE t1.id (+)= t2.id);

an I got an error: error while compiling statement: failed: parseexception line 2:26 cannot recognize input near 't1' ',' 'table2' in table source

Comment: "missing left parenthesis" error will come and 
Table 1 is having values 
Name    id

Amy     1
Bob     4
Josh    9
Sam     6

and Table 2 is having values

Value  id

.2     4
.7     6

Comment: I tried to run the following, but encountered an error:
`CREATE TABLE Table_C AS`
    `(SELECT a.* FROM table_a a, table_b b`
    `WHERE a.id (+)= b.id);`

But I got the following error in line 2: `error while compiling statement: failed: parseexception line 2:0 cannot recognize input near '(' 'select' 'a' in select clause`

Comment: This syntax throws an error for me, it doesn't like the comma between table1_t1 and table2_t2

Answer (score 0):

Create the result table

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE3 (Name STRING, id INT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Then insert into the new table using Join

```
INSERT INTO  TABLE TABLE3 SELECT t1.Name, t1.Id from Table1 t1 
JOIN Table2 t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id;
```

will give you the desired result.